# How to filter out the file path using grok filter and add as new field

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, elk

I want to filter out `scm_output` portion from `/lib/logs/scm_output.log` this file path and `abc_output` from this file path  , `/lib/logs/abc_output.log`, and add new fields as `scm_output` & `abc_output`.

I have tried this,

```
grok {
        match => { "[log][file][path]" => "%{PATH}%{GREEDYDATA:name}\.*+%{GREEDYDATA}.log" }
   }
```

But not getting any result.

I am new to ELK and GROK filter, please help me to filter these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below grok pattern should work for you

```
grok
{
match => {"message" => "%{GREEDYDATA:PATH}/%{GREEDYDATA:filename}.log"}
}
```

Keep Posted!!! Thanks !!!